# Convert SQL column null values to 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm new to SQL Server and I have an issue.

I have this view, in which some of the columns from the formulas are allowed to be null.

How could I convert these null values to 0 because if they are null, the result of the formula it will be also null.

Thanks!

```
CREATE VIEW vwAchizitii
AS
    SELECT
            ac_id
           ,[Company]
           ,No
           ,[ContractID]
           ,[Seller]
           ,[AcquistionDate]
           ,[Village]
           ,[Commune]
           ,[Area]
           ,[PlotArea]
           ,[FieldNo]
           ,[Topo1]
           ,[Topo2]
           ,[Topo3]
           ,[Topo4]
           ,[Topo5]
           ,[TotalAreaSqm]
           ,[OwnershipTitle]
           ,[CadastralNO]
           ,[Type]
           ,[Price]
           ,[NotaryCosts]
           ,[LandTax]
           ,[OtherTaxes]
           ,[AgentFee]
           ,[CadastralFee]
           ,[TabulationFee]
           ,[CertSarcini]
           ,[ProcuraNO]
           ,(price+notarycosts+landtax+othertaxes+agentfee+cadastralfee+tabulationfee+certsarcini) as TotalCosts
           ,(price+notarycosts+landtax+othertaxes+agentfee+cadastralfee+tabulationfee+certsarcini)/(TotalAreaSqm/10000) as RonPerHa
           ,(price+notarycosts+landtax+othertaxes+agentfee+cadastralfee+tabulationfee+certsarcini)/(TotalAreaSqm/10000*FixHist) as EurPerHa
           ,[DeclImpunere]
           ,[FixHist]
           ,(price+notarycosts+landtax+othertaxes+agentfee+cadastralfee+tabulationfee+certsarcini)/FixHist as EurHist
           ,[LandStatus]
FROM      
   nbAchizitii
```

Comment: Start with looking at the [`ISNULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function.

Comment: Use either `ISNULL` or `COALESCE()` function.

Comment: Why is this tagged .NET?

Comment: other already gave an answer. I would like to ask you why your fields may contain null? Do you need to make a difference between 0 and 'no value'? If you don't need to catch the "no value" value, please consider changing your fields into NOT NULL and provide a default value. Serge

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I already tried this but I make the insert from a form(I want to be able to let some fields empty) and if I don't put nothing in the respective field it will give me an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [ISNULL (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

eg

```
(isnull(price,0)+isnull(notarycosts,0)) as Total
```

Comment: Do you know how could I set the number of decimals for the formula result?

Comment: @user1820705: Have a look [decimal and numeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) eg. if you need two decimals `CAST(50/10 AS decimal(5,2)) `

Answer (score 10):

Well, someone should put in a word for ANSI standards:

```
coalesce(<column>, 0)
```

`isNULL` is specific to databases (and even does different things in some databases).

Comment: Thank you kind sir! It should be noted however, that IsNull is the faster of the 2 in MS SQL Server for simple single value operations.

Comment: @hajikelist . . . `isnull()` and `coalesce()` should be pretty much the same for *simple* operations.  `isnull()` is faster when the first argument is complex.  But they should be the same for a column reference.

Comment: MySQL COALESCE() function returns the first non-NULL value of a list

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
ISNULL([nullable field], 0)
```